# AngularFire & ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, select, firebase, angularfire

I am struggling to populate a select form element. Here is the syntax that I have so far. It will not grab the program.title and populate the ngOptions.

```
<select ng-model="student.program" ng-options="program.title for program in programList.title">
<option value="">Select A Program</option>
</select>
```

Here is the basic JSON structure of my data on Firebase:

`{
  "-JNIBeRDAuNN9c7SGZ91" : {
    "location" : "Online",
    "director" : "Shawn Clark",
    "title" : "Web Design & Development"
  },
  "-JNIBuaQlWyEyWRjONPa" : {
    "location" : "Online",
    "director" : "Walen Morrow",
    "title" : "Graphic Design"
  },
  "-JNIBmIwasMYOPRPupHl" : {
    "location" : "Campus",
    "director" : "Tracy Monohan",
    "title" : "Web Design & Development"
  },
  "-JNKGPNj-lGzqHJ92RTD" : {
    "location" : "Online",
    "director" : "Glen Speedy",
    "title" : "Theory of Animation & Physics"
  },
  "-JNK9oTO97PfSo-0wQfY" : {
    "location" : "Campus",
    "director" : "John Myers",
    "title" : "Instructional Design & Technology"
  },
  "-JNIC3Tldo-Qi3ru2ph7" : {
    "location" : "Campus",
    "director" : "George Narrow",
    "title" : "Graphic Design"
  },
  "-JNK8cdgdHKjH2meKl9x" : {
    "location" : "Online",
    "director" : "Stacy McNally",
    "title" : "Instructional Design & Technology"
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for

```
<select ng-model="student.program" ng-options="program.title for (id, program) in programList"><option value="">Select A Program</option></select>
```

Your JSON's root object is an object, not an array. [See angular documentation for object data sources](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uSylNtCVw5hsZ6k6bmQg?p=preview)

Comment: Well thank you so much Joel! That worked, now the only is that upon clicking the add button now I get all the data from that one object (title, director, and location). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Here the link to the app in question, you will note that all the data is showing up.

https://canvasapp.firebaseapp.com/#/manage-students

Comment: I do not understand. When i load the page, i see JSON in the program of study column. Nothing happens when i click add. If I solved your initial question, it is best to mark it as solved and open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: You rock Joel! I can't your answer up yet as my reputation points haven't reach 15 yet. But again you saved the day...

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code.

It should work:

```
<select ng-model="student.program" ng-options="program.title for program in programList"><option value="">Select A Program</option></select>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use programList.title use program.title in ng-options. Change your ng-options to ng-options="program.title for program in programList"

Comment: This is for arrays, not object data sources https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select